# Get all records where age is less than from a date difference in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to get all the records of children for which age is less than 5 years.

The date to calculate age should be a future date e.g 2021-08-12

$date and $age are custom.

$date can be any future date and $age is a number (e.g 5)

I have written the following but it is not working.

```
$children=Child::whereRaw('DATEDIFF('.$date.', date_of_birth) < '.$age.'')
                ->get();
```

Here date_of_birth is a column in DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after debugging i found a solution. The problem was that the $date was not passed as string due to which there were no days found and I had to convert the days into years. This may help to someone.

```
$children=Child::whereRaw('(DATEDIFF("'.$date.'",date_of_birth)/365) < '.$age.'')
          ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

To Avoid Raw Expressions and complex query You can use **Virtual Columns**

1.Add this to your Migration after `created_at` column **or you can create new Migartion**

```
$table->char('date_of_birth_year',3)->virtualAs('DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, date_of_birth)),"%y")');
```

Run your Migrations

Now You can Run the following query to get the records that is created at specific month

```
$yearsOld = ['01', '02', '03', '04'];

$childrens = Child::query()
    ->whereIn('date_of_birth_year', $yearsOld)
    ->get();
```

If you want to Know more check the Below links

1. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-modifiers
2. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use `whereBetween` method. And compare it to `now()` or any other datetime

```
Child::whereBetween('date_of_birth', [now()->subYears(5), now()])->get();
```

Comment: date_of_birth is a date stored in DB i only want to take a difference with a custom $date.
This query give me records between the two date. Not the solution!

Comment: @KaleemShoukat. I updated it to give a explicit solution. You should date_of_birth between now and now minus 5 years.

Comment: Thank you for the help but this is not the solution.